# Pass variable from JavaScript to Controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have these check boxes, whose value i am getting using JQuery

```
<div>
    <p> Type:
        <label>
            <input type = "checkbox" name = "types[]" class="filterType" value="Single"/>Single
        </label>
        <label>
            <input type = "checkbox" name="types[]" class="filterType" value="Double"/>Double
        </label>
        <label>
            <input type = "checkbox" name="types[]" class="filterType" value="Suite" />Suite
         </label> </p>

   <input type="submit" value="filter" onclick="exefunction()" />
</div>  


<script>
function exefunction() {
        var checkedVals = $('.filterType:checkbox:checked').map(function () {
            return this.value;
        }).get();
        var typesAtt=checkedVals.join('-');
        }
</script>
```

How can I pass the `typesAtt` variable to my `RoomController` where I can apply filters from database. this is the Index.cshtml view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At client side:

```
$.post("YourUrl",typesAtt,function(){
})
```

At Server side:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult YourActionName(string data)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Same as with everything. You simply make http request, and pass whatever you want(as query parameter or part of body in case of a POST request).

If you make ajax request with jquery you will have to write a handler in your frontend application.

Comment: I don't understand how to do that with http request.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep the input elements inside a form tag and use the correct input element names.

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Filter","Home"))
{
    <div>
        <p>
            Type:
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="types" value="Single" />Single
            </label>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="types" value="Double" />Double
            </label>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="types" value="Suite" />Suite
            </label>
        </p>    
        <input type="submit" value="filter"  />
    </div>

}
```

Now in your Filter action method, you can have a parameter called `types` which is a string array type.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Filter(string[] types)
{
    // to do : Return something
}
```

When user submits the form, the types parameter will be populated with the value of selected check boxes. For example, if user selected "Single" and "Suite", types parameter will be a string array of 2 items, "Single" and "Suite"

The important thing to remember is, your input element's name should match with the action method parameter name.